# Specialize std template for member struct

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I would like to have a class with the following structure:

```
class A {
public:
  struct key_type {};

private:

  std::unordered_map<key_type, some_other_type> m;

}
```

As far as I understand, to make that work I need to specialize `std::hash` and `std::equal_to` before `A::m` is declared but after `A::key_type` is declared, which makes it impossible, because I can't specialize the template *in* `A`. Afaik, there is also no way to forward declare (outside `A`'s definition) `A::key_type`.

Essentially my question is: Am I missing something, or is such structure impossible?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to workaround this situation.

1. Define a separate type.

   ```
   struct A_key_type {};
   namespace std {
       template <> struct hash<A_key_type> { size_t operator()(const A_key_type&); };
   }

   class A {
       typedef A_key_type key_type;
       std::unordered_map<key_type, int> m;
   };
   ```
2. Provide an explicit custom hasher type.

   ```
   class A {
       struct key_type {};
       struct key_type_hasher { size_t operator()(const key_type&); };
       std::unordered_map<key_type, int, key_type_hasher> m;
   };
   ```

Comment: I already planned to use solution 1. if it is indeed impossible (and solution 2. in a case where I want the key type private within the class).
Are you suggesting, that I'm not missing anything and it is indeed impossible?